# Joomla Mass Mail

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails

Its seams my Mass mail button is gone. 
User>Mass Mail is missing, Is there a way to re install it?
Searched the web and didn't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new security setting added in Joomla 3.x using which you can disable Mass Mailing.

To enable Mass Mailing:

1. Go to System -> Global Configuration -> Server Tab
2. In Mail Settings tab set No to "Disable Mass Mail" option.

Comment: Thanks Allot that was what i need. Using Joomla for 2 ears and didn't see it before.